# Cannot send emails using AWS SES and Rails' Action Mailer without IAM Policy settings for all domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send emails using AWS SES via Action Mailer in Ruby on Rails (v6). AWS provides `aws-sdk-rails` gem, and it makes to be easy to configure using SES, but I realized that it needs sendable permissions such as `ses:SendEmail` to ALL domains in SES.

```rb
# config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb
Aws.config[:credentials] = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(:aws_sdk, region: "us-east-1")
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :aws_sdk
```

```rb
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@example.com"
end
```

An AWS IAM User has the following policy, which allows to send emails from only `example.com` domain.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/example.com"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I got an error like the following when workers send emails.

```
ERROR: Processor failed: User `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/my-group/my-iam-user' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/other-domain.com'
```

I think the SDK verifies whether all domains have sendable permissions by default, but I couldn't find to specify a target domain. What should I do?

Comment: The SDK should not be validating against all domains, can you print out the mail sending options if this error occurs?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I'm not sure that the SDK has a specification to validate all domains, but at least it requires permissions in them in my project...
I've not written any configurations except for these codes because `aws-sdk-rails` is black box.

Comment: I just realized the error requires `ses:SendRawEmail` to `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/DESTINATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` . Is this correct behavior? otherwise, my configuration is wrong...

Comment: Hmm that is not correct, it should be the sending email domain not the target domain. Are they perhaps the wrong way round?

Comment: I just set `Resources` to `"*"` and add the destination email address to verified email addresses for sandbox-mode, then I get a successful response! I'm getting confused

Comment: Oh, are you still in sandbox mode? If so then yes this is very restrictive. You should come out of that and then try again. Whilst in sandbox you can only send emails to verified emails

Comment: Yes I know, but I didn't know that it requires `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/DESTINATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` in sandbox mode...

Comment: Yep, always forget that part about sandbox mode. I generally add a domain and immediately try to get out of sandbox mode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused as a result of the domain being in a sandbox account. Within the [SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) the following states are identified:

- You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.
- You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.

To send emails **to** any email address you need to move your from domain(s) [out of sandbox mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).